cv.namedWindow title is not shown correctly(shows garbage)
NamedWindow
import cv2 as cv 
img_c = cv.imread('candy.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv.namedWindow('Image', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow('Image', (600, 300))
cv.imshow('Image', img_c)
cv.setWindowTitle('Image', 'MyCandy img_c')
cv.waitKey(0)

Above code shows title correctly on Ubuntu 24.04 with opencv 4.9.0 and python 3.11.8.
However in Ubuntu 22.04(same cv and py), the title is not shown correctly as shown in figure.
Anyone knows what I am missing?
Any comment will be appreciated...
